# Import excel into access parse error with value list

Tags: ms-access, excel-2010

I have to import an excel sheet straight into an existing access table. In one value there is a short text value list. However I set out the data in the cell on excel and in access I can not get it to parse into the value list (The values are exactly the same as what are in the list). Does anybody know how it should be set out to successfully import. At the minute it gives me a parse error and leaves it blank.

Thank you in advance,
Alex

[Value List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQGad.png)

Answer (score 0):

Link the Excel sheet as a linked table.

Then create an append query, using the linked table as source, that modifies and expands the records as needed, and appends these to the target table.